# Where does Fedora (31+) store the list of apps for which Qt Wayland is disabled?

Tags: fedora, qt, wayland

Since Fedora 31 Qt Wayland is [on by default](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Qt_Wayland_By_Default_On_Gnome), which has led to [some compatibility problems](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1773650) with some apps, which was solved by [a fallback list](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2019-690a29587a). One can of course turn off Qt Wayland just for some app on launch by prepending `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb`, but assuming one wants to perma-add an app to the Fedora fallback list (which ain't included in it, but should be), where is that list located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list is [hard-coded in a patch to the source code](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/qt5-qtbase/blob/0dced0680680d2d60184a00d6b89d6c7c0ea29de/f/qtbase-use-wayland-on-gnome.patch), you can’t add to it without recompiling.